# Trace I/O call from VM to Hypervisor to Hardware

Tags: debugging, kernel, virtualization, esxi, hypervisor

In our project we want to trace how the call goes from the VM to the Hypervisor to the disk,we are using a type 1 Hypervisor (Vmware ESXI).We want the I/O trace just likes logs eg:VM (Code )-->Some Function of hypervisor Code -->To the Disk .
Can any one please provide any reference ,way or any links where I can find the above.I  have searched on Net ,also have a meeting with professor for his guidance  (but thats still time ,hence need to be prepared before that ) .

Answer (score 0):

you can get the toolchain for different OS versions from VMware website.

EX. ESXi 5.5
https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=ESXI550_OSS&productId=353